# cmake - adding a submodule

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build a test project with a "submodule/subproject".

The compilation fails with:

```
example_01/src/main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: inc/foo2.hpp: No such file or directory
#include "inc/foo2.hpp" // #include "submodule/inc/foo2.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

My files:

#### main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(hello_world)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_subdirectory("submodule")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
src/main.cpp 
src/foo.cpp)
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "inc/foo.hpp"
#include "inc/foo2.hpp" // #include "submodule/inc/foo2.hpp"

int main()
{
    foo();
    foo2();

    return 0;
}
```

#### foo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "inc/foo.hpp"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

#### foo.hpp

```
void foo();
```

#### submodule cmakelist

```
project(submodule_dummy1)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/foo2.cpp)
```

#### foo2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "inc/foo2.hpp"

void foo2()
{
    std::cout << "FuuTwo\n";
}
```

#### foo2.hpp

```
void foo2();
```

Is there something else I need to declare so it can "see" the submodule header?

## UPDATE

### Tree

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── inc
│   └── foo.hpp
├── readme.md
├── src
│   ├── foo.cpp
│   └── main.cpp
└── submodule
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── inc
    │   └── foo2.hpp
    └── src
        └── foo2.cpp
```

### New main cmakelist

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(hello_world)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/submodule)

add_subdirectory("submodule")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    src/main.cpp 
    src/foo.cpp)
```

### new error message

```
Scanning dependencies of target hello_world
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX executable hello_world
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo2()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/build.make:99: hello_world] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You need to include directory, which contains required header (`inc/foo2.hpp` in your case).

Comment: Please add your file / subdirectory structure for completeness -- right now it is not really clear how the file you listed are organized. (We can see what you _assume_, but it would be nice to double-check if those assumptions actually hold true.)

Comment: I don't use the `add_subdirectory()` feature myself; does `include_directories()` settings carry over from the parent?

Comment: @DevSolar please see "tree"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/submodule)
```

in the main CMakeLists.txt.

Also you need to compile and link `submodule/src/foo2.cpp` (by adding it as argument to the `add_executable` command in your main CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: looks as this brings me 1 step closer, thank you. now the main cannot see foo2() function.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: thank you. this works.. but by including a submodule source file to the MAIN cmakelist, i kinda miss the point of separating project and its submodules. is there no option to include source files from submodules in the submodules cmakelist?

Comment: if each submodule has source code that must be linked to the main executable, consider creating a [static library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) in each submodule (named after the submodule itself), so you can easily link all these libraries into the main executable, without knowing the name of the individual source files to link.